# Why is it called Overlapped I/O?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, terminology, overlapped-io

All I can find is tutorials on how to use Overlapped I/O, but I can't find why is it called like that.

Is it because for example I can read something from a socket, and then read something else before necessarily the first read returns the bytes read?

Comment: Everybody else calls this "asynchronous I/O."

Comment: Well, you can issue a read request, (or multiple read requests for the same, or different, sockets).  The actual reading will be done for you and you will be notified upon completion.

Comment: It's because you can be performing multiple I/O operations at the same time, i.e., they overlap one another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the idea was (20 years ago) that you could start an IO, perform some computation or other work and later wait for the result. This is rarely done today. I think this idea comes from a time where `select` and `poll` were considered state of the art.

A better name would be asynchronous IO. That's what every other platform seems to call it. [In fact the MSDN documentation mixes the two terms.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Windows does also use the phrase "asynchronous I/O", e.g., https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @usr what is the current state of the art today? Are you saying that `select` and `poll` are deprecated?

Comment: @Rich they are not officially deprecated but the resulting programming model has issues with flexibility, code quality, scalability and absolute performance. Using epoll or kqueue is not hard with a library. Can't see why an informed person would not pick that route over select/poll. And then you still have the choice to use threads over async IO which is a more complicated trade-off.

Answer (score 15):

The classic meaning dates back to the 1960's (or ealier), where overlapped I/O meant that multiple I/O transfers (normally each I/O to a different device) could occur at the same time (like concurrent reads from tape and writes to disk). An alternative classic name for this was concurrent I/O. This could be accomplished via interrupts and/or hardware similar to DMA (in those days, some of the DMA hardware implementations were more like a set of small processors)

Example article for IBM mainframe:

[Overlapped I/O - IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idad400/uoiowb.htm)

Answer (score 6):

**Overlap** operation in Microsoft Windows means nothing else as **asynchron** in everybody else OS-language.

To stick to your example, you start a read on a socket and do not wait for success but do something completely different (maybe read on a different(!) socket). Then ask if the first operation is finished. 
You can also set an event-handle for that. Or give a `CALLBACK` function which is called on completion.
In that case, the first call "overlapped" the rest of your operations.

Look also at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O).

My guess why Microsoft is(was) calling it overlapped is that it is not like starting a thread, more like to start an async task at a time there was no standard name for it. It is more like `std::async` than `std::thread`.

Comment: 'do something completely different', well, you can do the same thing, if you wish.  You can issue multiple read requests against the same, or different, socket/s before any completion notifications are handled.